# Trying to bind a resource template to a user control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have an idea of using a template approach to style my user control.

It is a custom menu-control. It is implemented as a listview for the time being.

I would like to have different styles of my user controls depending on where it is used in my application. The application will have a top menu, right menu and a bottom menu, at least that's the idea for now. I want to use the same user control for all menus, but I would also like to style them differently without having different versions of the user control.

So my approach to this has been to define different ControlTemplates in a Resource/Style file. These ControlTemplates are used in the main application xaml in a binding on the SelectedTemplate dependency property of the menucontainer user control.

The complete user control code follows. It is the Field SelectedTemplate that is of interest here:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.Views.Menu.CustomMenuContainer"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MyApp.Client.ViewModels"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Client.Views"
         xmlns:commongui="clr-namespace:MyApp.CommonGui;assembly=MyApp.CommonGui"
         xmlns:menu="clr-namespace:MyApp.Client.ViewModels.Menu"
         xmlns:webControls="clr-namespace:System.Web.UI.WebControls;assembly=System.Web"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 

         d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="1200">
<Grid>

    <ListView Background="Transparent" 
              BorderBrush="Black" 
              BorderThickness="2"   
              x:Name="MenuList" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems}" 
              SelectionChanged="MenuList_OnSelectionChanged" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}" 
              SelectionMode="Single" >
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Name="MenuPanelTemplate">
                <UniformGrid IsItemsHost="True" x:Name="MenuPanel">
                </UniformGrid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>

        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Name="MenuItemStyle">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkSeaGreen" />
                        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{Binding SelectedTemplate}" />
                    </Trigger>                       
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
     </ListView>
</Grid>
```

SelectedTemplate is dependency property on the user control:

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SelectedTemplate", typeof(ControlTemplate), typeof(MenuContainer), new PropertyMetadata(default(ControlTemplate)));

 public ControlTemplate SelectedTemplate {
     get { return (ControlTemplate)GetValue(SelectedTemplateProperty); }
     set { SetValue(SelectedTemplateProperty, value); }
 }
```

I have added a SelectedTemplateChanged method to control what happens when the template changes:

in the constructor:

```
 DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(SelectedTemplateProperty, GetType()).AddValueChanged(this, SelectedTemplateChanged);
```

then the implementation. I know that we enter this code when the Template is set in the binding of the user control, but I cant figure out how to apply the template to the listview selecteditem.

```
private void SelectedTemplateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //How to access and set the template of the ListView (named MenuList in the xaml) selected item from 
   //code behind?

   //pseudocode follows:
   //Find the resources of MenuList
   //find trigger for isSelected
   //apply the SelectedTemplate on a setter of the IsSelected trigger...
}
```

Following is the usage of the user control in the main window.

I bind the different ControlTemplates from the resource file (see below) to the SelectedTemplate of each of the menu1:MenuContainer controls

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.Client.Views.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Client.Views"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MyApp.Client.ViewModels"
    xmlns:menu1="clr-namespace:MyApp.Client.Views.Menu"
    xmlns:menu="clr-namespace:MyApp.Client.ViewModels.Menu"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModels:MyAppViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="1200">
<Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding MenuViewModel.TopMenuHeigth}" MaxHeight="100" />
        <RowDefinition Height="600*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding MenuViewModel.BottomMenuHeight}" MaxHeight="70"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="800*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding MenuViewModel.RightMenuWidth}" MaxWidth="160"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Name="TopMenuGrid" Row="0" Column="0" ColumnSpan="2">
        <menu1:MenuContainer x:Name="TopMenu" 
                       MenuOrientation="Horizontal" 
                       SelectedItem="{Binding MenuViewModel.SelectedHeaderMenuItem, Mode=TwoWay}"  
                       MenuItems="{Binding MenuViewModel.HeaderMenuItems}"
                       SelectedTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderMenuSelectedItemTemplate}">
        </menu1:MenuContainer>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Name="RightMenuGrid" Column="1" Row="1">
        <menu1:MenuContainer x:Name="RightMenu" 
                       MenuOrientation="Vertical" 
                       SelectedItem="{Binding MenuViewModel.SelectedRightItem, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                       MenuItems="{Binding MenuViewModel.RightMenuItems}"
                       SelectedTemplate="{StaticResource RightMenuSelectedItemTemplate}">
        </menu1:MenuContainer>

    </Grid>
    <Grid Row="1" Name="ContentGrid" Column="0" ColumnSpan="1">
        <TabControl Name="ContentTabControl" 
                SelectedIndex="{Binding MenuViewModel.SelectedPage}">
                <TabItem Header="Home Page">
                <TextBlock>Here comes the home page</TextBlock>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Name="DetailMenuGrid" Grid.Row="2" ColumnSpan="2" Column="0">
        <menu1:MenuContainer Background="Aquamarine"
                        x:Name="BottomMenu" MenuOrientation="Horizontal" 
                        SelectedItem="{Binding MenuViewModel.SelectedBottomItemItem, Mode=TwoWay}"  
                        MenuItems="{Binding MenuViewModel.BottomMenuItems}"
                        SelectedTemplate="{StaticResource BottomMenuSelectedItemTemplate}">
    </menu1:MenuContainer>                    
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

the styles:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Client.Resources"
                xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
                xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:MyApp.CommonGui.Helpers;assembly=MyApp.CommonGui">
<ControlTemplate x:Key="BottomMenuSelectedItemTemplate" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="true" 
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                CornerRadius="5" x:Name="border"
                >
        <StackPanel>
            <Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=TextBlockContent}" 
                       Child="{Binding SelectedControl}" 
                       Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" 
                       Placement="Top" VerticalOffset="-2" AllowsTransparency="True" 
                       IsOpen="{Binding IsActive, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <helpers:AutoRepositionPopupBehavior/>
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </Popup>
            <ContentControl 
                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center">

                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <ToggleButton  
                        Height="64"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background}"
                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                        x:Name="TextBlockContent"  
                        Content="{Binding Name}"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                        IsChecked="{Binding IsActive}"
                        ></ToggleButton>
                  </Grid>
            </ContentControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="HeaderMenuSelectedItemTemplate" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="true" 
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                CornerRadius="5" x:Name="border"
                >
        <StackPanel>
            <ContentControl 
                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockContent" Text="{Binding 
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ContentControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="RightMenuSelectedItemTemplate" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="true" 
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                CornerRadius="5" x:Name="border"
                >
        <StackPanel>
            <ContentControl 
                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <ToggleButton  
                       Height="64"
                       BorderThickness="0"
                       Background="{Binding 
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                               Path=Background}"
                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                        x:Name="TextBlockContent"  
                        Content="{Binding Name}"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                        IsChecked="{Binding IsActive}">
                    </ToggleButton>
                </Grid>
            </ContentControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I hope I get my question clearly through here:
I need to know what goes into the SelectedTemplateChanged method of the code behind of the MenuContainer user control in order to set the style of the selected item of the ListView.

But I am sure this could be done more elegantly. I am rather new to "advanced" xaml and styling with templates, so I have gotten a little stuck. I have searched the forum for hours trying to find a solution but I haven't been successful yet.

Is it possible to achieve this without the code behind of SelectedTemplateChanged?

Any help appreciated, both direct solution to my question or alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to bind to the `SelectedTemplate` property of the `UserControl` using a `RelativeSource`:

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Name="MenuItemStyle">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkSeaGreen" />
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{Binding SelectedTemplate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks! That was all I needed :)